# Crear un objeto de mongo con un campo de la misma colección

Tags: mongodb

Tengo una colección en mongodb donde necesito cambiar la estructura de esto:

```
{
  nombre_contacto: "nombre del contacto de prueba"
}
```

a esto:

```
{
  contactos: [
    {
      nombre: "nombre del contacto de prueba",
      puesto: "puesto"
    }
  ]
}
```

Pero necesito mover el campo que ya estaba para no perder información, por lo que hice esto:

```
db.prospectos.updateMany({}, {$set: { "contactos": [{"nombre": '$nombre_contacto', "puesto": ""}]}});
```

Pero no me puso el valor del campo nombre_contacto si no que puso el estring "$nombre_contacto"

```
{
  contactos: [
    {
      nombre: "$nombre_contacto",
      puesto: "puesto"
    }
  ]
}
```

Alguien me puede decir que estoy haciendo mal, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Se desea realizar una actualización de documentos en una Base de Datos [MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/), de tal forma que los campos a ser actualizados / añadidos contengan valores de otros campos del mismo documento.

El problema de tu consulta es que la expresión `"$nombre_contacto"` no se refiere al campo `nombre_contacto` del documento actual, sino que resuelve a un tipo `String`. En una operación de [actualización múltiple](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/#db-collection-updatemany), usando el [operador de actualización](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/) llamado [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set), los valores pasados al campo, son considerados como valores literales (*Number, String, etc*) y no como expresiones que devuelvan un valor. El comportamiento que esperas es el de un proceso de agregación.

**SOLUCIÓN**

**MongoDB 4.2 o superior**

Si dispones de MongoDB 4.2 o superior, [puedes hacer uso de etapas de agregación en una operación de actualización](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), usando el [operador de agregación](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) llamado [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html), o su alias llamado `$set` (a partir de la versión 4.2 de MongoDB)

De esta forma podrías usar la siguiente agregación que se parece al documento que estabas pasando como documento de actualización, excepto por una diferencia:

```js
[
  {
    $set: { // $set es un alias para $addFields
      contactos: [
        {
          nombre: "$nombre_contacto",
          puesto: "puesto"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Como puedes observar se trata de un `Array` y no de un `Object` como lo tenías en tu código.

La consulta podría verse de la siguiente forma:

```js
db.prospectos.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      contactos: [
        {
          nombre: "$nombre_contacto",
          puesto: "prueba"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

Puedes ver un ejemplo del código anterior en el siguiente [MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/l1QVBTdDIYP).

**MongoDB 3.4 hasta 4.0**

Si no dispones de esta característica debido a tu versión de servidor, puedes usar una combinación de proceso de agregación y el método [`save()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) aplicado sobre la colección.

Por ejemplo, puedes hacer la siguiente operación:

```js
// nuestra etapa de agregación (es un Array)
let aggregate = [
  {
    $addFields: { // el alias $set sólo está disponible en MongoDB 4.2 o superior
      contactos: [
        {
          nombre: "$nombre_contacto",
          puesto: "puesto"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

// obtenemos un cursor:
let result = db.prospectos.aggregate(aggregate);

// iteramos el cursor y salvamos cada documento en la colección
while(result.hasNext()) {
  db.collection.save(result.next());
}
```

De esta forma, lo que estás haciendo es procesar los datos mediante una agregación y luego salvar (sobreescribir) cada documento de la colección con el documento resultante de la agregación.

Puedes leer más información sobre [cómo iterar un cursor](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/index.html) en el Shell de MongoDB.

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono, aunque aún no alcanzo a entender muy bien el funcionamiento de mongodb